# Deserializing a JSON object with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: javascript, json, vb.net, bootstrapper, javascriptserializer

I'm writing a bootstrap for my application. It downloads the latest version of the app and installs it.  I have a problem with the JSON parsing part of the app.   I am trying to get the info from this JSON:

```
{
    "Launcher": {
        "latestver": "<the latest version of the launcher>",
        "url": "<url to the launcher pack>",
    }
}
```

To parse it, I created a structure:

```
Public Structure Launcher

    Public latestver As String
    Public url As String

End Structure
```

Then I tried to get the values from the JSON on the internet:

```
    Dim client As New WebClient() With {.Proxy = Nothing}
    Dim Json As String = Await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("<url to the launcher.json>")

    Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim thisLauncher As Launcher = jss.Deserialize(Of Launcher)(Json)

    RemoteLauncherVer = thisLauncher.latestver
    LauncherPackUrl = thisLauncher.url
```

But when I checked the values with a MsgBox, the values were `Nothing`:

```
    MsgBox(RemoteLauncherVer)
    MsgBox(LauncherPackUrl)
```

Can someone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a class at the root level.  Try making your classes like this:

```
Public Class RootObject
    Public Property Launcher As Launcher
End Class

Public Class Launcher
    Public Property latestver As String
    Public Property url As String
End Class
```

Then deserialize like this:

```
Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim thisLauncher As Launcher = jss.Deserialize(Of RootObject)(json).Launcher
```